# Ubuntu doesn't detect my usb interface

Tags: 14.04, sound, usb, alsa, soundcard

I'm having trouble trying to make a M-Audio Fast Track MKII work in Ubuntu 14.04

I got a dell inspiron pc with Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 installed with low latency kernel, and tweaked for audio and music recording. Everything was working perfectly, the usb audio interface was working as expected (in 16 bits, because its a 1.1 usb compliance device), and something happened, i don't know, maybe an update i didn't reviewed and double-checked. The next time i turned my computer on, everything was working, except the communication between the soundcard and the pc. Now it doesn't even show on "sudo lsusb" and the system can't identify its ID's (ID ffff:fffe).

I have a dell laptop which i use to work in another endeavours, that has the standard Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 (generic kernel). For curiosity, i've tried to plug the interface in it, but nothing really happened. The ubuntu in the laptop also can't identify its ID's.

I tried a lot of solutions on the internet, many didnt work (of course) and some that looked promising i couldn't do it because instructions were outdated, etc. But all were the type of solution that:
1. tried to compile drivers into the kernel
2. tried to reboot/reinstall/reconfigure alsa
3. tweak alsa modules
But looks like ubuntu 14.04 have different fisiology and works differently, and solutions that might have worked in 12.04, 13.04, 13.10 don't work anymore.

I have tried installing other distro's (kxstudio, avlinux, tangostudio), but none made it work (i also installed kxstudio and tried it out for a while - and still didn't got my soundcard). I just haven't tried in a pc with windows (i dont have it at home).

The interface is still working though (leds blinking), and haven't moved from the place it was before, when it was working. I also just tried with another cable

I don't know what else to do, can please someone help?
i'm almost giving up (buying a new interface - switching OS's is not a option to me, since my computer is all set up, and im really into linux)